# How do you release the ISP lease using an Ubuntu v9.04 live CD, like Windows does?

Tags: ubuntu, internet, connection

I use Windows 2000, and I’m able to release the ISP (Verizon) lease using the WNTIPCFG applet, but I cannot do the same when I use the Ubuntu v9.04 live CD. I have used just about all methods I found on the Internet, and none has worked, so please make sure your suggestion really works before answering. If the lease is truly released, a Windows connection on the same line will get a new lease immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [dhclient](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dhclient8.html) command, which is the DHCP client.  Try this:

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first release the current IP address using:

```
sudo dhclient -r
```

Then if you need to renew your address, it can be done using:

```
sudo dhclient
```

Comment: I tried all those. They are rather simple and don't work, as I said in the details of my question.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to run these commands?

Comment: No, but it is obvious they do not quite work. Some will break off the connection but will not get the lease to be released.

Comment: What do you mean by "lease to be released"? How do you know?  The lease is actually managed by the DHCP on the ISP side.  When you renew after releasing, the DHCP server can still give you the same address, by releasing it you are just telling the DHCP server you are done using that address, it doesn't imply anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough status to comment. How do you know the address is not being released.  You said the connection is broken off, but the address is not released.

Verizon may reassign an address based on MAC address, but if you release it and then try to renew it from Windows, the MAC on Windows is different and Verizon may give you an entirely different address.

Or, are you trying to get an entirely different address and you keep getting the same one whenever you renew?  In that case, Verizon is probably reusing the last address released in which case you will need to leave your machine offline for maybe an hour or two before renewal will give you a new address.